# Поток ввода/вывода: почему нет ошибки при работе с файлами без явного их закрытия

Tags: python, language-lawyer

Пробую такие конструкции:

```
file = open('file.txt').read()
open('copy_file.txt', 'w').write(file)
```

Почему-то все работает... Из опыта работы с другими языками я ожидал увидеть некоторые странности в связи с открытыми потоками (я их не закрываю), но все отлично работает. Даже при многократном запуске. И не похоже, что есть проблема утечки памяти. Почему так ? В документации ничего не нашел на эту тему...

Comment: Имя file вводит в заблуждение. Используйте `text` вместо этого. Имя file можно использовать  в Питоне для результата вызова open() функции. read() метод возвращает строку, а не файл.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас память используется только для хранения содержимого `file.txt` в переменной file.

А открытые потоки закрываются и собираются сборщиком мусора сразу как заканчивается чтение или запись, так как у вас нет ссылок на эти объекты.

Про сборку можно почитать по этой ссылке: http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо.

Comment: file это просто содержимое файла, в виде одной строки. На нее естественно тратится память, которая равна размеру этой строки.

Comment: Точно сразу закрываются? То есть нет нужды в with?

Comment: @vitidev нет,  язык не гарантирует этого и в частности на Pypy не известно когда файл закроется. На CPython, файл закроется сразу как только ссылок на него не останется. На таких системах как Windows или если скрипт много файлов может открывать или чтобы не думать о нетривиальных деталях реализации сборки мусора *следует детерминированно  закрывать файлы* к примеру, используя with-конструкцию.

Comment: Да конечно, с PyPy несколько сложнее, так как его сборщик мусора не основан на подсчете ссылок и когда удалится объект большой вопрос. Использование with,более желательно, да и код получается более наглядным и правильным, сразу видно блок в котором происходит открытии ресурса.

Comment: @jfs а почему на windows сборщик мусора не закроет поток ?

Comment: @faoxis и на Windows может закрыть в какой-то момент. Важно что не гарантировано что ваш код это сразу сделает и на Windows ошибка при доступе может выбрасываться, если файл открыт в другом процессе (поэтому более заметно, если файл сразу не закрыт).

Answer (score 5):

В реализации python - PyPy сборщик не закрывает файлы и поэтому может быть утечка. Поэтому конечно лучше использовать универсальный with. Это очень поможет если вы вдруг захотели перенести проект на PyPy так как он в большинстве случаев быстрее стандартной реализации python - CPython.
Перенести в данном случае - просто запускать на PyPy.

А также при попытке прочитать незакрытый в PyPy файл вы получите пустую строку. (если файл открыт и для записи)

Comment: Ссылки в коде вопроса на файл нет, поэтому опасности пустой ввод получить при повторном чтении нет. Но могут быть [другие проблемы](http://goo.gl/AZzf8h)